# Доступ к элементам MainWindow из статического класса

Tags: c#, wpf

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как обратиться к TextBox'у с именем `textBox1`, размещенному в `MainWindow`, из метода статического класса `SomeStaticClass`?

```
namespace Programm1
{
   public partial class MainWindow : Window
   {
      public MainWindow()
      {
         InitializeComponent();
      }
   }

   public static class SomeStaticClass
   {
      public static void Test()
      {
         MainWindow.textBox1.Text = "Done!"; // Ошибка 
      }
   }
}
```

Ошибка:

> Для нестатического поля, метода или свойства требуется ссылка на
>   экземпляр.

Comment: Нужно передавать параметром экземпляр класса MainWindow в статический метод. Вы явно что-то делаете не так раз вам приходиться MainWindow передавать в статический метод. Попытайтесь переосмыслить дизайн вашей программы.

Comment: Вам не должно этого хотеться. Что делает ваш статический класс? Почему вам вдруг понадобилось из статического класса главное окно?

Comment: Планирую организовать некий журнал проводимых операций - "log". Чтобы при выполнении некоторой операции статический класс записывал в журнал ход.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Сделать статическую переменную `Instance` в которой будет форма и обращаться к ней.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public static MainWindow Instance { get; private set; } // тут будет форма

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Instance = this; // инициализируем статическую переменную
    }
}


public static class SomeStaticClass
{
    public static void Test()
    {
        if (MainWindow.Instance != null) // обращаемся к ней из статического класса/метода
            MainWindow.Instance.textBox1.Text = "Done!";            
    }
}
```

Возможно, подход не самый правильный, но достаточно простой и понятный.

---

Предложу еще более простой вариант. Переписать статический метод, чтобы он принимал компонент `TextBox` и менял его свойство, вот так:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SomeStaticClass.Test(this.TextBox); // передаем наш TextBox в метод
    }
}


public static class SomeStaticClass
{
    public static void Test(TextBox textBox) // принимаем наш компонент
    {
        if (textBox != null)
            textBox.Text = "Done!"; // меняем его значение
    }
}
```

В этом подходе никаких статических переменных, просто добавлен параметр в метод.

Comment: Всё-таки лучше бы было создать интерфейс `IMainWindow` со свойством или методом и давать ссылку через него, а не напрямую как вы показали: `public static MainWindow Instance { get; private set; }`

Comment: @Bulson, написал первый же рабочий пример, который пришел в голову. И написал: *Возможно, подход не самый правильный, но достаточно простой и понятный*. Думаю, Вы бы могли предложить свой вариант в качестве ответа :)

Comment: Я вам лучше плюсик поставлю :)

Answer (score 3):

Тут вопрос больше не к wpf, а к архитектуре Вашего кода. Для доступа к нестатическим св-вам класса MainWindow Вам так или иначе потребуется экземпляр класса MainWindow.

```
public static class someStaticClass
{
    public static void test(MainWindow wnd)
    {
        if (wnd != null && wnd.textBox1 != null)
            wnd.textBox1.Text = "Done!";      
    }
}
```

Далее Вам нужно будет получить доступ к экземпляру MainWindow. Это можно сделать например создав его самостоятельно (но это врятли Вам подходит):

```
var wnd = new MainWindow();
...
someStaticClass.test(wnd);
```

Либо (что более распространено) например из code-behind по событию:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.SomeEventHandler += MainWindow_SomeEventHandler;
    }

    private void MainWindow_SomeEventHandler(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        someStaticClass.test(this);
    }

}
```

Я бы посоветовал Вам не использовать такой подход, а изучить mvvm. Тогда менять св-во текст Вы будете из вьюмодели через механизм привязки. (Без использования класса MainWindow вобще)